# CSS Override text-overflow: ellipsis

Tags: css

ellipsis will add `'...'` to text by default if we have `'text-overflow: ellipsis`', but my scenario i need to overide this by `two stars` * *. How we can achieve this is **Pure CSS**?

Note: It should support All browsers like IE9+ and chrome

As some peoples asking example adding this,
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow

Comment: For doing this you need javascript. Its not possible with pure css

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: @priya_singh: Expecting CSS workaround. Hoping some CSS experts will help me

Comment: @NenadVracar: Example added

Comment: This will not really work exactly as the css's ellipsis feature, but it can give you a hint of how to create something similar: https://jsfiddle.net/dekelb/vuxfk0hk/

Comment: @Dekel:    Change width: 99px; character cutted to half

Comment: This is why I said it doesn't really behave exactly as ellipsis :)

Comment: You should be able to just specify a string for `text-overflow`, but browser support varies. In Vivaldi it doesn't work.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Yeah Mozilla Supporting Many, but my primary focus on Chrom and IE

Answer (score 5):

You can apply a trick using pseudo elements like `:after`.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
#div1 {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 99px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#div1:after {
  content: '**';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 2px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<p>This div uses "text-overflow:ellipsis":</p>
<div id="div1">This is some long text that will not fit in the box</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Change width: 99px; character cutted to half

Comment: @LearnReact Updated the answer. Try it now.

Comment: Sorry bro, Can you check with  width: 89px;  it is breaking

Comment: The `:after` pseudo class will not work the same as the ellipsis. You will have to check if you have enough content to cut&display the ellipsis, and you can't really do this with the `:after` pseudo class.

Comment: @LearnReact I agree with Dekel. This will not work as same as ellipsis. This is just a trick to override ellipsis.

Comment: Nice attempt! Unfortunately it behaves weird when selecting the text. One should always consider if specific styling features  like this are worth degrading user experience for.